# Magento 2.2.8 - Change page title for Newsletter Management page

Tags: magento2, newsletter, page-title, magento2.2.8

I am trying to change the title of the /newsletter/manage/ page. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by overriding the \Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Manage\Index controller.

di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Manage\Index" type="Myvendor\Mymodule\Controller\Override\Manage\Index" />
</config>
```

\Myvendor\Mymodule\Controller\Override\Manage\Index class:

```
<?php
namespace Myvendor\Mymodule\Controller\Override\Manage;

class Index extends \Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Manage\Index
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();

        if ($block = $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_newsletter')) {
            $block->setRefererUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        }
        $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('[[My custom title]]'));
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Replacing the [[My custom title]] with your title

Comment: Thank you. I found a solution using the layout xml - app/design/frontend/FOLDER/THEMENAME/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml

...
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Contact Us</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
...

Does either solution have an advantage over another?

Comment: I think your solution is much better than mine :-)